# Hard coding URL vs passing URL as component's props in react

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I have a component which fetches a URL and then displays it on the chart.

```js
const PieChart = ({ url }) => {

const [data, setData] = useState([{}])
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
  async function dateFetching() {
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const js = await response.json()
    setData(js)
    setLoading(false)
    
  }
  dateFetching()

}, [])


    const chart = {
      labels: ['Success', 'Failure', 'Running', 'Warning'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of every status',
          data: [1, 54, 22, 1],
          backgroundColor: [
            '#299629',
            '#ed3232',
            '#008eb8',
            '#CC7722',
          ],
          borderColor: [
            '#299629',
            '#ed3232',
            '#008eb8',
            '#CC7722',
          ],
          borderWidth: 1,
        },
      ],
    };
  if (loading) return (<Loading />)

  return (
    <>
    <div style={{ position: "relative", margin: "auto", width: "45rem" }}>
    <Pie data={chart}/>
    </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PieChart;
```

I tried passing the URL directly in the component and it's ok.

I noticed that when I try to pass the URL as the component props, I get an 304 error in network section of chrome and in console I get:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`

**But** if I pass the URL directly it works just fine.

Any idea why is this happening?

I expect to get the result as same as hard coding the URL when I pass the URL as component props.

Comment: Just a side note. HTTP code 304 is not an error. 304 Not Modified means that the requested resource hasn't been modified since the last time it was requested, so there's no need to fetch it again and transfer data in vain.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check where you pass your prop. I'm not sure how you pass the `url` as a prop but it seems there's a syntax error. Make sure you add a closing tag or something and I think you should add `url` to your useEffect's dependency array.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    async function dateFetching() {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const js = await response.json();
      setData(js);
      setLoading(false);
    }
    dateFetching();
  }, [url]); // This will let React know when to fetch
```

Comment: Hi, In my code you can see that in the first line I passed url like { url } as PieChart component's prop. Thanks for your suggestion.